# What is wrong in my setup of a Pervasive ODBC connection from Access?

Tags: ms-access, odbc, pervasive, linked-tables, pervasive-sql

I'm trying to connect an Access 2010 database to a Pervasive dataset.  My computer is Windows 7 32 bit.  I've set up an ODBC connection through the ODBC administrator, but when I try to open a table in Access 2010 I get a message saying the ODBC connection has failed.  What am I doing wrong?

So I've set up an ODBC connection.  When I test it, the test completes successfully.

[image]

Then I go to Access and use the linked table manager to change the link to the database.  The link seems to be refreshed successfully.

[image]

However, when I try to open the table, I get a message saying "ODBC-call failed" with no further information

[image]

Also, I can open the Pervasive client on my machine and view the table, it's just in Access I can't view it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the design of "pr_earn", possibly is different from the design of the table you were using .

The design is not automatically updated in MSAccess.  An alternative is to remove and link the table again.

best regards!